# Cant use a loc function in python (pandas) after filtering

Tags: pandas, filter

my code below:

Step 1: my_list= ['SalePrice']

Step 2: print(correlations.loc['MiscVal'][0])

Step 3: filterTable  = correlations[correlations.index.isin(my_list)]

Step 4: print(filterTable.loc['MiscVal'][0])

Step 2 prints the right result, but step 4 gives an error. Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Output of the filtered table below

[image]

Comment: Steps *1* and *2* are not very important. Add to your post the content of *filterTable* (some representative example of your data) and describe more precisely your error.

Comment: OCR is painful - provide data not an image

Comment: *MiscVar* is a column.  so `filterTable.loc['MiscVal'][0]` should be `filterTable.loc[:,'MiscVal'][0]`